# How do I chain multiple async generators / iterators in parallel?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

Is there an equivalent to itertools.chain(*iterables) that works with async iterators? One key requirement would be to get available data from an async iterator as soon as it's available (i.e. no naive chaining).

*Update: Note that one key difference to the duplicate question, is that the answer below lets you identify the triggering async generator.*

Answer (score 3):

The following piece of code solves this problem:

```
import asyncio

class InternalStopAsyncIteration(Exception):
    """A special stop exception that also returns the finished generator's key."""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

async def anext(key, gen):
    try:
        return key, await gen.__anext__()
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        raise InternalStopAsyncIteration(key)

async def combine_async_generators(**gens):
    pending = {anext(key, gen) for key, gen in gens.items()}
    while pending:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for i in done:
            if isinstance(i.exception(), InternalStopAsyncIteration):
                gens.pop(i.exception().key)
            else:
                key, val = i.result()
                pending.add(anext(key, gens[key]))
                yield key, val

# The following will print:
# a 0.5
# b 1
# a 0.5
# a 0.5
# b 1
# b 1
async def gen(x):
    """An async generator that sleeps a bit, then yields the given value."""
    for i in range(3):
        await asyncio.sleep(x)
        yield x

async def run():
    async for k, v in combine_async_generators(a=gen(0.5), b=gen(1)):
        print(k, v)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())
```